# how to convert 2014-10-22 11:25:00 to 2014 -Oct in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset as 'data1' in the form of 2014-10-22 11:25:00 and another dataset with corresponding concentrations 'conc1' and the 3rd dataset is the 'locations' - I would like to plot locations vs conc1 with different colored months. Let me know if you can help me with it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without any data provided, here is my best guess with what you're looking for. The `zoo` package can help process dates if you're looking for month and year combination. The `format()` function could also extract the data you're looking for. If the data are in a table - the following would work.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

data = data.table( 
    'data1'=c('2014-09-22 11:25:00','2014-10-22 11:25:00','2014-11-22 11:25:00'),
    'conc1'=c(8,5,20),
    'locations'=c(1,2,3)
)

data[ , 'data1':=as.Date(data1)] # convert to dates
data[ , 'data1_mon':=as.yearmon(data1)] # convert to month-year

p = ggplot( data=data)
p = p + geom_point( aes(x=locations,y=conc1,color=as.factor(data1_mon)), size=4 )
print(p)
```